# Why Is my json-object from AJAX not understood by javascript, even with 'json' dataType?

Tags: ajax, json, drupal

My js code simply gets a json object from my server, but I think it should be automatically parsed and turned into an object with properties, yet it's not allowing access properly.

```
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/misc/json-sample.js',
      data: {href: path}, // THIS IS THE POST DATA THAT IS PASSED IN; safe2ignore.
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (datax) {

  if (datax.debug) {
    alert('Debug data: ' + datax.debug);
  }  else {
         alert('No debug data: ' + datax.toSource()  ) ; 
      }
```

The /misc/json-sample.js file is:   [ { "path": "examplemodule/parent1/child1/grandchild1", "title": "First grandchild option",  "debug": "First grandchild option",   "children": false } ]

(I have also been trying to return that object from drupal as follows, and the same results.) 
Drupal version of misc/json-sample.js:

```
 $items[] = array(
      'path' => 'examplemodule/parent1/child1/grandchild1',
      'title' => t('First grandchild option'),
          'debug' => t('debug me!'),
      'children' => FALSE
    );
    print  drupal_to_js($items);
```

What happens (in FF, which has the toSource() capability) is the alert with 'No debug data: [{path:"examplemodule/parent1/child1/grandchild1", title:"First grandchild option", debug:"First grandchild option", children:false}]'
Thanks

Comment: I am confused, you are expecting the debug field to be in your returned object from Drupal, but you do not have this field in `/misc/json-sample.js`? Does it work if you add the field to your hard-coded js file?

Comment: Sorry, I mistakenly posted the wrong version of the json-sample.js file and alert output.  I fixed that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the Content-Type header to application/json.

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
print  drupal_to_js($items);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tested the change recommended by Michael in the drupal version.  It does seem this directive is now part of the header, as when I load the URL directly from localhost as /ra/js then FF asks me "what should FF do with this application/json" -- BUT the jquery app still does not parse the results properly and the same alert is called.

Comment: I think I've got it.   [ { "path": "examplemodule/parent1/child1/grandchild1", "title": "First grandchild option", "debug": "First grandchild option", "children": false } ] is an ARRAY of objects!  Without the [], the .js dummy-filed was parsed properly.  Hence, I'm probably referencing the .debug wrong, as that is not an element of the list but an element of the first item in the list.